# JavaScript/AJAX Generate Url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, url

I have no web developing experience at all so explanation with details would be appreciated! Let me know what other information if you think my questions is not clear.

I have a webpage, say the url looks like this:

```
www.mycompany.com/category1
```

And it contains a parametric search box. There is an apply button in the parametric search whose source code looks like this:

```
<input type="button" value="Apply" id="Button" class="button-link" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">
```

It redirects you to another page after you click the apply button which contains the search results and the URL looks like:

```
http://www.mycompany.com/jsp/search/browse.jsp?N=2001109&No=0&getResults=true...
```

I took a look at the source code of the mycompany.com/category1 page and I cannot see the existence of the string '2001109' which looks like contains the information of my search..

***I am wondering how is the URL generated?***

It might be generated by JQuery/JavaScript/PHP..(I don't know any of these) and how could I locate the file which is used to generate the URL maybe using Chrome Web Developer Tools. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **parametric search box** will be in a html form tag `<form>` this is the default behavior of form if you don't specify the `method` attribute this will be assumed as the `get` method to request a server ,**2001109** is the value of one of the `<input>` field within a form if you see the html of the form there will be an `action` attribute which tell where to send the form information which contains this **http://www.mycompany.com/jsp/search/browse.jsp** url as i said there was a get request method is used therefore all the information within input fields lie in the `<form></form>` will be appended in the url which commonly known as `query string` if your request method is defined as `post` then information within a form will not be appended in the url it will be in browser

[**form**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form)

[**html-get-vs-post**](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/general-miscellaneous/html-get-vs-post/)

[**Query_string**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, dianuj, I am currently diving into the code and it did acted as you mentioned. Which IDE - editor are you using so you could test your html code and it does the syntax highlight? thanks

Comment: I use jet brains ide for php ,html but it depends on you which programming language you use http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/